# Obtaining visitors time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on scheduling. My time zone is GMT +0100 CET, and I'm available on Mondays at 09:00AM my local time.

However I would like that time to be adjusted so the user sees it in their time. This means it could change time, but also day. F.ex if they're GMT -10:00 Hawaii.

Is there a way for me to obtain a visitors time zone via the controller and then show the time using:

`@datetime_given.in_time_zone(visitors_time_zone)`

Or should this be done in a different way entirely?

Comment: I would suggest an approach using Javascript and doing it client side assuming you don't have anything stored on the visitor

Comment: It's probably generally better to ask the user what their timezone is. A user can move timezones or could be spoofing it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the setup of your app. You can use [gem 'momentjs-rails'](https://github.com/viclim/moment_timezone-rails), for changing timezone to anonymous users. Let’s say you want to show the time in visitors local timezone and you don’t want them to sign in or log in to your website. For example, your server is in Europe region. In your views you parsed time and `DateTime.parse()` only show Mondays ( Previous/current Monday till next one comes ) :

```
<h1>My schedule:</h1>
<div class="timestring">
   I'm available on Mondays 9 AM my local time.<br>
   Converted in your local timezone: <span class="time"><%= DateTime.parse("Mon 09:00 +01") %></span>
</div>
```

After installing `momentjs-rails gem`, in  `application.js` add require moment library and format datetime to visitors timezone :

```
   //= require moment

   $(document).ready(function() {
     var format = 'LL hA';
     $('.time').each(function() {
       this.textContent = moment(this.textContent).format(format);
     });
});
```

This code above is trivial and it [works](https://local-time-zone.herokuapp.com/). Try changing your computer's date and time settings to Hawaii, and the date & timezone will reflect changes. Again it depends on your setup and app logic. Would you like to manipulate with timezone with registered users?